# For Loop and program for extracting words that start with a specific character and printing them in a single file line

Tags: python

So I've been trying to use a for loop to extract key words that start with a certain letter but I'm not sure how to get the code to work properly , I know that the program file and text file have to be in the same folder , but I have that part working it's just the program that's just giving me a hassle is all.so far here is my for loop code:

```
f = open("file_name.txt","r")
eng_list=list(f)
letter=("Enter First Letter")

for letter in index[0]:
   if letter=eng_list[0]:
      print(word)
   else:
      print(None)
```

Comment: What part of the above code is not working? What is your expected vs your actual output?

Comment: and format your code please

Comment: There's a couple things wrong with the code you've posted. First you're assigning `letter` to the first character of `word`. Based on your question, it sounds like you want the other way around. Also, `for` loops shouldn't have `else` blocks; it doesn't make logical sense. If you swap `letter` and `word[0]`, and print `letter` instead of `word`, you might get what you're looking for.

Comment: `if word[0]==letter:` @ahota its perfectly fine for a for loop to have an else block in python

Comment: @ahota A `for` loop _can_ have an `else` clause, but it only makes sense if there is a `break` in the loop.

Comment: @JoranBeasley huh, I just looked that up. I've never seen it before. I think in this context although it's technically okay, it's not correct.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: my expected output is a list of all the letters starting with the character the user enters

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like:

```
with open('file_name.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    text = my_file.read()
    for word in text.split():
        if word[0] == my_letter:
            print(word)
```

I am making some assumptions about what you want, though.